# How do I perform a bubble sort in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

Question: You have been given an array A of size N . you need to sort this array non-decreasing order using bubble sort. However, you do not need to print the sorted array . You just need to print the number of swaps required to sort this array using bubble sort

**Input Format**

The first line consists of a single integer N denoting size of the array. The next line contains N space separated integers denoting the elements of the array.

**Output Format** Print the required answer in a single line

**Constrains** 1 <= N <= 100
1 <= a[i] <= 100

My Solution which returns nothing

```
def bubbleSort(arr, arrSize):
    temp = 0
    swap = 0
    for i in range(arrSize):
        for e in range(arrSize-i-1):
            if arr[e] < arr[e + 1]:
                temp = arr[e + 1]
                arr[e] = temp
                swap += 1
    return swap
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. This function must return a number. Are you printing it out?

Comment: I am trying to solve the problem using a function. After I have understood the implementation then I can easily do it using the `Input` Function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem in your code is you are returning `swap` variable it's not array.
And your swapping of elements is incomplete. In python you can swap two elements easily using this notation `a, b = b, a`.

And one more thing you don't need to return the array changes will automatically reflect in original array.

try this:

```
def bubbleSort(arr, n):
    swap = 0
    for i in range(n - 1):
        for j in range(n - i - 1):
            if arr[j] > arr[j + 1]:
                arr[j], arr[j + 1] = arr[j + 1], arr[j]
                swap += 1
    return swap
a = [5, 2, 3, 1, 4]
print('swaps =',bubbleSort(a, 5))
print(a)
```

**Output:**

```
swaps = 6
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: @WannaBeBayesian what would you expecting from return